# Installation of mlpack on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c++, mlpack

I have performed a mlpack installation using the OS version of package manager (Ubuntu 22.04):

```
sudo apt install libmlpack-dev mlpack-bin libarmadillo-dev
```

Now I am trying to compile a simple program. However no file `mlpack.hpp` was installed in my system. There exists a folder `usr/include/mlpack` but it does not contain the required header. In [quickstart](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack/blob/master/doc/quickstart/cpp.md) nor in [installation guide](https://www.mlpack.org/getstarted.html) there is no information that this file should be installed/downloaded separately. How to make it compile? Where do I take this file from?

The code from the mlpack website I am trying to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mlpack.hpp>

using namespace mlpack;

int main()
{
  // Load the data from data.csv (hard-coded).  Use CLI for simple command-line
  // parameter handling.
  arma::mat data("0.339406815,0.843176636,0.472701471; \
                  0.212587646,0.351174901,0.81056695;  \
                  0.160147626,0.255047893,0.04072469;  \
                  0.564535197,0.943435462,0.597070812");
  data = data.t();

  // Use templates to specify that we want a NeighborSearch object which uses
  // the Manhattan distance.
  NeighborSearch<NearestNeighborSort, ManhattanDistance> nn(data);

  // Create the object we will store the nearest neighbors in.
  arma::Mat<size_t> neighbors;
  arma::mat distances; // We need to store the distance too.

  // Compute the neighbors.
  nn.Search(1, neighbors, distances);

  // Write each neighbor and distance using Log.
  for (size_t i = 0; i < neighbors.n_elem; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << "Nearest neighbor of point " << i << " is point "
        << neighbors[i] << " and the distance is " << distances[i] << "." << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `mlpack.hpp` is directly in `/usr/include` so that one does not need any further `-I...` switches.   I can compile your question just fine on Ubuntu 23.04 with the mlpack 4.0.1 release I use there:

```
$ g++ -o question question.cpp
$ ./question 
Nearest neighbor of point 0 is point 3 and the distance is 0.449757.
Nearest neighbor of point 1 is point 2 and the distance is 0.918409.
Nearest neighbor of point 2 is point 1 and the distance is 0.918409.
Nearest neighbor of point 3 is point 0 and the distance is 0.449757.
$
```

As for the narrower 'where is `mlpack.hpp` question, you can also ask Debian / Ubuntu:

```
$ dpkg -S mlpack.hpp
libmlpack-dev:amd64: /usr/include/mlpack.hpp
$
```

PS Per the comment, the screenshot of [my PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eedd/+archive/ubuntu/misc/+packages) with the updated packages:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I have no such file as mlpack.hpp. The mlpack binaries and -dev are present. It just didn't install during execution of `sudo apt-get install libmlpack-dev mlpack-bin libarmadillo-dev`

Comment: I feared that.  There were _substantial_ changes between mlpack 3.* and 4.*. The package on Ubuntu LTS is sadly a little behind.  You could install `mlpack` from source or take advantage of my PPA where I built an updated package for my use from the Debian package. My PPA is at https://launchpad.net/~edd/+archive/ubuntu/misc/+packages and I added a screenshot of the mlpack 4.0.1 packages you can get from there.